# How to add a user to a ManyToManyField when creating User in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

**Models.py:**

```
class RegularUser(MyUser):
    MyUser.is_staff = False
    MyUser.is_superuser = False

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Usuario Regular'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Usuarios Regulares'



class AdminUser(MyUser):
    usuarios = models.ManyToManyField(RegularUser, help_text="Selecciona los usuarios que administra", blank=True)
    MyUser.is_staff = True

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Administrador'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Adminsitradores'
```

I want the next: I log in the admin site as AdminUser, which have staff permission. Then I can create RegularUsers. When I create a new RegularUser I want link this Regular User to the AdminUser through the ManyToManyField so this RegularUser owns to the AdminUser. And the AdminUser could manage this RegularUser in the adminSite.

I want some like this:

class RegularUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    ...

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=RegularUser)
def link_user_admin(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.adminuser = request.user
```

But adminuser isn't a field of RegularUser. And using request in signals is forbidden. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You now have only set the *parent* attribute. As a result, all the `MyUser`s are staff.

Comment: No. Just AdminUsers are staff. This attribute is settled down in the child instance. Anyway that isn't the question. Thanks

Comment: Willem is correct. You can't set those attributes like that; your code is totally broken. But for your actual question, are you sure you don't want a ForeignKey rather than a many to many?

Comment: To fix the staff problem I'll remove the MyUser.is_staff of the child model. I have to set AdminUser.is_staff to True some way. I think that is a ManyToMany, because RegularUsers could be managed by many AdminUsers as well as AdminUsers can manage many RegularUsers. Is not that the purpose of M2M relationships¿?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I have found the solution. I need to use the request in the post_save method. However, you can't use it in Django signals, so it's possible to use the Django save_model method which you can get access to the request.

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj:
            # Save the object
            super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
            # Add the user instance to M2M field of the request.user (The admin User) who create the RegularUser 
            request.user.adminuser.usuarios.add(obj)
```